# start emacsclient with focus from command line

Tags: emacsclient

When I start emacsclient from command line as below:

```
emacsclient -a '' -c "$@"
```

It always starts in the background (terminal window on top of emacsclient window), so I have to use mouse to click the window to switch to emacsclient.

It's really frustrating, can I get emacsclient to focus the frame that pops up when invoked from command line?

[image]

Comment: This is probably more a function of the window manager/desktop environment, than of emacs/emacsclient. In my case, the new frame pops up on top of the terminal window, e.g. (Gnome 3.20 on Fedora 24).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You might be able to use the `server-switch-hook` and raise the frame. Something like:

```
(add-hook 'server-switch-hook #'raise-frame)
```

If that leaves you without focus on the new frame you might try something like this instead:

```
(add-hook 'server-switch-hook (lambda () (select-frame-set-input-focus (selected-frame))))
```

If you are looking to have a shell command to bring up an Emacs frame (without specifying one or more files to edit), you can also do this from the command line:

```
emacsclient -e "(raise-frame)"
```

Comment: It doesn't work. but it sounds like if add a filename at the command line, emacs will popup to foreground but without file to open, it will stay at background.

Comment: If you don't need to pass file name arguments you can also call a function from the command line, e.g.: `emacsclient -e '(raise-frame)'`

Comment: Your (select-frame-set-input-focus (selected-frame)) advice worked for me.

Comment: I also couldn't get this to work using `server-switch-hook`, but it did work by adding the `select-frame-set-input-focus...` function to `server-after-make-frame-hook`. Not sure if there are any downsides to doing that instead...

Answer (score 3):

This problem was also reported as an issue ([see spacemacs issue #7078](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/7078)). The solution of using a [wrapper script](https://github.com/TheBB/dotfiles/blob/master/scripts/ecli#L5) posted there worked for me. For completeness I will add the content of the script here:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

if [[ "$#" -lt 1 ]] ; then
    emacsclient -c -e \
                "(select-frame-set-input-focus (selected-frame))" \
                "(delete-other-windows)" \
                "(spacemacs/home)" else
    emacsclient -c -e \
                "(select-frame-set-input-focus (selected-frame))" \
                "(delete-other-windows)" \
                "(find-file \"$1\")" fi
```

I do not have enough reputation points to comment here. But it would be great if information about where to place the `server-switch-hook` could be added to the answer by @glucas. In the end I did not get any of his solutions to work in a fully straightforward way...